# I get the client side middleware, but how do I secure a users resources on S3?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I get the client-side middleware - but I don't want a situation where a user accidentally or maliciously deletes the resources of other users.

How can I secure resources on S3 so that a user can only delete their resources and not the resources of any other user?

Comment: Not sure if that helps. But I use Laravel as a middleman between user and S3. User files are stored privately on the S3. If user wants any of his file, the request is validated and the file must go through my server. It's not as efficient as direct download from S3, but could work for smaller files. Besides, I'm doing full download to the server, wonder if that could be upgraded to the re-stream mechanism.

Comment: @AndriusRimkus you could give public permissions of read-only to your resources when storing the file from your server (through an [IAM User](https://aws.amazon.com/es/iam/) with full access). This way, the file woudn't need to go through your server anymore and i'll be secured... unless they hack AWS, lol.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying, I rarely get a chance to work on this aspect of my project. FYI my users resources on S3 are not listed by user_id, but by YYYY/MM/DD when the resources are created eg mysite.com/s3-bucket/2019/02/16/resource_name.png for example

Answer (score 6):

> I don't want a situation where a user accidentally or maliciously deletes the resources of other users

When you set up your S3 Bucket you configure the permissions that any person has on your bucket resources. If I'm not wrong, everything is treated as "private" by default.

What you also need to do is configure a [IAM User](https://aws.amazon.com/es/iam/) and grant him access (through a [Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)) to let him read and also write data in your bucket. If you do this properly, only this `user` can do the important thing: write. All of this resource "writing" (creating/updating/deleting) needs to be done on your server on behalf of this "IAM user" with the user key/secret credentials.

This grants you to be the only way to make changes in your S3. With this setup, your resources are secured even when your malicious users know the path to your bucket, because these users will only have the "read" access at most.

I recommend you to follow [this article](http://stayregular.net/blog/how-to-upload-images-using-amazon-s3-and-laravel) (or [this](https://www.clickittech.com/es/aws/subir-archivos-amazon-s3-laravel) one, in case you understand spanish) as a guide to set up your S3 bucket.

---

As a response of this other concern:

> How can I secure resources on S3 so that a user can only delete their resources and not the resources of any other user?

All of this operations needs to be handled in your server to ensure integrity/security. Your users don't need to have direct access to your resources in order to be able to modify them.

Maybe your question goes in this direction:

**What if a troll user wants to change someone else's profile picture if the system has an endpoint that looks like this?**:

```php
POST /users/{id}/update-photo
```

In this case, you could let a malicious user (lets say user `id` equals `10`) to have access to someone else's resource:

```php
/**
* he/she could do this:
*/
POST /users/23/update-photo  // <-- id=23
/**
* instead of:
*/
POST /users/10/update-photo  // <-- id=10
```

How to avoid this? with auth checking and route "masking".

```php
/**
* Instead of this:
*/
POST /users/23/update-photo // <-- user id=23
/**
* Try this kind of endpoint:
*/
POST /profile/update-photo // <-- note that we disabled the ability to specify a user id
```

How to recognize the user? In case of an API through the token, in case of a web call through the session. In this example, to identify the user you do something like this:

```php
public function updatePhoto(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user(); // <-- now we ensure the user is id=10

    // the rest of the code..
}
```

Of course, I'm just assuming this is one of your concerns, but is a simple example of how this kind of validation can be implemented in server-side to ensure the protection of your resources.

Comment: Hi HCK, many thanks for the reply. Do you think that client side verification, for example accessing resources by user_id is enough? Are AWS Access Control Lists overkill?

Comment: @Dazzle sorry for the late reply, it seems I missed this notification. I think that a mix of security in each layer always pay-off. In your front-end, you could make route validation; in your backend, check if the user is allowed to perform such an action; an in your external dependencies/services (like AWS) set your policies to comply with your specifications such as the credentials/keys with which actions are performed. This should be your way to go. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this using Amazon S3 access control list (ACL). ACLs enable you to manage access to buckets and objects. Each bucket and object has an ACL attached to it as a subresource. It defines which AWS accounts or groups are granted access and the type of access. When a request is received against a resource, Amazon S3 checks the corresponding ACL to verify that the requester has the necessary access permissions.

When you create a bucket or an object, Amazon S3 creates a default ACL that grants the resource owner full control over the resource.

Amazon S3 APIs enable you to set an ACL when you create a bucket or an object. S3 also provides API to set an ACL on an existing bucket or an object. Following API methods are available:

- Set ACL using request headers— When you send a request to create a
  resource (bucket or object), you set an ACL using the request headers. Using these headers, you can either specify a canned ACL or specify grants explicitly (identifying grantee and permissions explicitly).
- Set ACL using request body— When you send a request to set an ACL on
  an existing resource, you can set the ACL either in the request
  header or in the body.

A sample ACL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AccessControlPolicy xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <Owner>
    <ID>Owner-canonical-user-ID</ID>
    <DisplayName>display-name</DisplayName>
  </Owner>
  <AccessControlList>
    <Grant>
      <Grantee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CanonicalUser">
        <ID>Owner-canonical-user-ID</ID>
        <DisplayName>display-name</DisplayName>
      </Grantee>
      <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
    </Grant>

    <Grant>
      <Grantee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CanonicalUser">
        <ID>user1-canonical-user-ID</ID>
        <DisplayName>display-name</DisplayName>
      </Grantee>
      <Permission>WRITE</Permission>
    </Grant>

    <Grant>
      <Grantee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CanonicalUser">
        <ID>user2-canonical-user-ID</ID>
        <DisplayName>display-name</DisplayName>
      </Grantee>
      <Permission>READ</Permission>
    </Grant>

    <Grant>
      <Grantee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Group">
        <URI>http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers</URI> 
      </Grantee>
      <Permission>READ</Permission>
    </Grant>
    <Grant>
      <Grantee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Group">
        <URI>http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery</URI>
      </Grantee>
      <Permission>WRITE</Permission>
    </Grant>

  </AccessControlList>
</AccessControlPolicy>
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html