# How can I ***securely*** enable a user to delete their resource on AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52683482/i-get-the-client-side-middleware-but-how-do-i-secure-a-users-resources-on-s3) three months ago but I am still looking for an answer.

I get the client-side middleware - but I don't want a situation where a user accidentally or maliciously deletes the resources of other users.

How can I secure resources on S3 so that a user can only delete their resources and not the resources of any other user?

Comment: suggestion: delete your answer and put a bounty on the question you already asked

Comment: ok thanks- never used that before. Would appreciate an answer above if anyone could be so kind

Comment: What exactly do you mean by client side middleware? What is the structure of your system and how are you mapping users to their S3 content?

Comment: Hi- thanks. Client side middleware- only allow the delete request to be accessed if it matches the correct user_id. I'm using laravel php backend. I just want to make sure on AWS that only the specific user can delete a resource that belongs to them, and no others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get the client side middleware, but how do I secure a users resources on S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52683482/i-get-the-client-side-middleware-but-how-do-i-secure-a-users-resources-on-s3)

Comment: I literally referenced that duplicate in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it is not possible to restrict S3 against your application users (not AWS users) because S3 has no notion about any such specific user. And it is not your user that is deleting the content from S3 but your application itself, be it running on EC2 or Lambda for which you need to specify an IAM role so that it can actually do that.

No IAM configuration will help you here as you can either allow EC2 instance/Lambda to delete it or not. But it is the same EC2/Lambda, no matter which user initiated the request.

The only option here is to protect it via the application itself. Store mapping between users and their S3 content in a DB and performs application level check whenever any delete request is initiated. If you configure your application correctly, then the only way how someone can delete content of someone else is by getting access to their account credentials (or your AWS account with S3 administration rights). And if someone can impersonate someone else, then no protection that AWS provides could be of any use anyway (maybe except S3 MFA-delete protection but that is not applicable for scenarios such as this).

The way to go is to create tight test cases for your application considering this area to minimize chance of potential bug in application.

Here are some other suggestions/best-practices to make it less likely that malicious/accidental deletions occur.

1. use separate instances for your web server and DB server
2. place DB into a private subnet and allow only outbound connection to the Internet via NAT instance/gateway
3. only allow inbound connection from the security group associated with your web server (possibly SSH connection for administrative purposes if your are not using AWS managed DB - but only from a specific IP address)
4. store only hashes of your users' passwords in the DB
5. **allow versioning on your S3 bucket**, that way, even if an object in S3 is deleted (delete-marker is created as the most recent version of the object), you can always restore it if needed
6. make sure that only authenticated users can delete stuff

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Correct- the client/user sends a request that delegates to a single AMI user who creates & deletes the resource. So far my application logic is that only the authenticated user can send a delete request and delete the resource associated with their account. But I am worried about the security of this in production - I don't want to discover a situation where a malicious user figures out how to send delete requests to the resources of other users. Is there such a user => resource mapping available for S3?

Comment: @Dazzle There is only AMI user/role/group - S3 mapping so the answer is no. I have added some light guidelines that you may consider (specifically the one about object versioning)